# How can I build C source with Windows Geany via cygwin call?

Tags: cygwin, geany

Is it possible to set such a build command in it, which will compile source via **cygwin** call?

The default command in preferences is `gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f"` which calls **MinGW**, but some files can be compiled with **cygwin** version of **gcc** only (those which have linux specific libs like termios.h etc).

I tried this `c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "gcc -Wall -o %e %f"`, it works just like the default line, it again doesn't build those files with linux libs.

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably work alright if you set the command to:

```
C:/cygwin/bin/gcc -Wall -o %e %f
```

According to [some documentation](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html), Cygwin imports Windows environment variables, so even launching `gcc` from within Cygwin `bash` it might still find the wrong `gcc` (ie. MinGW one) due to Windows `PATH` environment variable. Here's a blurb from those docs:

> The PATH environment variable is used by Cygwin applications as a list of directories to search for executable files to run. This environment variable is converted from Windows format (e.g. C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows) to UNIX format (e.g., /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows) when a Cygwin process first starts...

You might need to tinker with the linker's library search paths (ex. LD_LIBRARY_PATH) and `gcc` include directories too.